# Need to validate local and remote branch before push

Tags: git, githooks

I am trying to create a checkpoint using Pre-push hook in GIT where i am checking if the local branch and the remote branch name is same or not.

And allow the push only if local and remote branches are same. I was trying something like this in pre push sample hook file but its not working. Please suggest.

```
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
if [ "$local_ref" != "$remote_ref" ]
then
        echo " Please check Remote and local branch names";
        exit 1

else
        exit 0
fi
done
```

UPDATE: My local branch is *Mybranch* in "git push command" and remote branch is *refs/for/Mybranch*

So even if my branch names are same its giving me error, How can I extract only branch name from remote excluding /refs/for?

Git push command:

```
git push origin Mybranch:refs/for/Mybranch
```

Comment: Remove `else exit 0`. Make sure the name of the hook is precisely `pre-push` and it is executable.

Comment: Hi this is also giving me error when my branch names are same, because am pushing my change to Gerrit/review branch

Thus my Local = Mybranch
and Remote= refs/for/Mybranch

how can I cut refs/for/ from remote_ref variable?

Comment: When you push a branch, `local_ref` is `refs/heads/Mybranch` and `remote_ref` is `refs/for/Mybranch`.

Comment: yeah but I just want to compare Mybranch and Mybranch as local and remote respectively, so am trying: while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
    do
    remote_ref >> remote.txt
 remote_ref1 = cat remote.txt | cut -d'/' -f3
 rm remote.txt
 if [ "$local_ref" != "$remote_ref1" ]
 then
   echo " Please check Remote and local branch names"\n
   exit 1
  
 else
   exit 0
 fi
 done'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should not assume `refs/heads/` or `refs/for/`, because your hook will be run for tag pushes (`refs/tags/`) and other pushes (e.g., refs/notes/, perhaps refs/stash, and so on).

Note that you (or anyone) can run, e.g., `git push there refs/heads/master:refs/for/something refs/tags/v1.2:refs/tags/v1.2 refs/remotes/origin/master:refs/heads/master` to request a push of three things simultaneously, which is why you have to read all the requests in a loop in the pre-push hook.

---

You suggested in a comment that you are using:

```
remote_ref >> remote.txt
remote_ref1 = cat remote.txt | cut -d'/' -f3
rm remote.txt
```

which has some syntax errors.

It's wiser to *check* the prefix, and if it's what you expect and wish to handle, strip *the prefix*.  Don't just extract the third word, since that will break if you are using branches named `feature/tall`, for instance, or are working with references with additional structure beyond the first two components (remote-tracking branches work this way for instance, though normally you would not push them).

In sh/bash script language, you can write, e.g.:

```
case $local_ref in
refs/heads/*)
    local_type=branch
    local_short=${local_ref#refs/heads/}
    ;;
*)
    local_type=unknown
    ;;
esac

case $remote_ref in
refs/heads/*)
    remote_type=branch
    remote_short=${remote_ref#refs/heads/}
    ;;
refs/for/*)
    remote_type=gerrit
    remote_short=${remote_ref#refs/for/}
    ;;
*)
    remote_type=unknown
    ;;
esac
```

Now that you have decoded the reference types and found short versions for known cases, you can write your per-case logic, and later extend it as appropriate:

```
case $local_type,$remote_type in
branch,branch|branch,gerrit)
    # push from branch to branch, or from branch to gerrit:
    # require that the shortened names match exactly (for now)
    if [ $local_short != $remote_short ]; then
        echo "push to $remote_type requires paired names" 1>&2
        echo "but you are pushing from $local_short to $remote_short" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
    ;;
*)
    # echo "unknown reference type - allowing" 1>&2 # uncomment for debug
    ;;
esac
```

All of this would then go inside the main `while read ...` loop.  If you make it to the end of the loop, *all* the references you are pushing have been verified (since none were rejected by the echo-and-exit code).

Comment: Accepted answer.
Appreciate your help on this, it worked for me.

Just one help, If you can explain how the below extraction works:

    remote_short=${remote_ref#refs/heads/}

Comment: The shells have a carefully defined syntax for "variable substitution" or "parameter expansion" (different documentation uses different terms for this). `$var` is the most obvious, but what if you want to expand `$x` followed by the letter `y`? So they have `${x}y` to do that. Inside the braces, they allow further modifications. The details vary from one shell (bash) to another (sh, dash, ksh, etc) but all support `${var#word}` which means "remove leading prefix pattern". There are many more: for bash specifically, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help!:)